# "pre-" and "post-", but what about "suf-"?

Tags: prefixes

Is there a prefix related to “suf-” the way “pre-” is related to “post-”?

In my opinion, “pre-” seems to mean leading, “post-” means bringing up the rear (like a post script). “suf-” would seem to have more of the idea of a caboose (the end of something), and as such, maybe there isn't something related that has the idea of beginning.

Comment: _Suffix_ comes from the Latin _sub_, 'under'. The extra F comes from assimilation with the F in _fix_.

Comment: Can you pairs of words with pre/post and then the analogous situation with 'suf' and the gap you're looking to fill?

Comment: re: *“suf-” would seem to have more of the idea of a caboose (the end of something)* -- not necessarily. See: John (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96234/pre-and-post-but-what-about-suf/96237#comment195799_96234) and Colin (http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96235/14666)

Answer (score 5):

People have already said that *suf-* is a form of *sub-* (it can also be found as *suc-*, *sug-*, *sum-*, *sup-*, *sur-* and *sus-*).

What they left out is that it's opposite is *super-* or *sur-*. Yes, that does mean that one of the forms of *sub-* is exactly the same as one of the forms of its opposite! Languages that form organically over thousands of years aren't always logical.

A lot of cases with *sub-* and its variants have no logical opposite though, since e.g. *subcutaneous*  means below the skin, but "above the skin" makes no sense, since we don't have any bit of us above the skin.

The example you give though, is an exception again. As *suffix*'s antonym is *prefix*, because they don't have perfectly corresponding component parts. Again, English isn't always logical.

Comment: *supracutaneous* is widely known and used in STM literature.

Comment: @Kris thanks, that's interesting and also reminds that *supra-* is yet another form of *super-*.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can think of at least one example where all four are used: phonetic segmentation and segmentational units. _Presegmental_ (appearing before a segment), _postsegmental_ (appearing after a segment), _suprasegmental_ (being applied to something larger than a segment, standing thus ‘above’ individual segments), and _subsegmental_ (individual features ‘under’ a segment) are all used in phonetics.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, if what we need is essentially the antonym of *underlying* state of an entity with respect to another, the generally adopted prefix would be ***supra-*** (considered the antonym of *infra*). The other generally used prefix in this sense is ***super-*** in certain cases.

***supra***:
[above](http://www.yourdictionary.com/supra-prefix), over or greater than. (*prefix*) An example of supra is *supraorbital*, which means situated above the eye's orbit.
*[above](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supra)* (MW)
adverb *[above](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/supra)*, especially when used in referring to parts of a text. [compare *infra*. Origin: 1400–50; late Middle English < Latin *suprā* (preposition) on top of, above, exceeding, (adv.) on top, higher up; akin to super-]

Examples:
*supraorbital* and *suborbital* flight
*measurement of sub-second and supra-second durations*
*sub-glacial and supra-glacial sediment*

Answer (score 1):

*Suf-* is a combining form of the Latin prefix *sub-*, (as John says). This has a literal meaning of "under", and you can see it with that meaning in words such as *submarine* and (with a transfer of meaning) *subdivide*.

But it is very often used in other metaphorical ways, so that the meaning of the word with the prefix is difficult or impossible to guess: *suffer*, *subtend*, *sublime*, *suffuse*, *subtract* etc.

I'm not quite sure what the meaning is that you are imputing to the prefix, so I can't offer a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think what corresponds to “suf-“ (as in suffix) is “pre-“ (prefix) as well.

*“Affixation is, thus, the linguistic process speakers use to form different words by adding morphemes (affixes)[:] at the beginning (prefixation), the middle (infixation) or the end (suffixation) of words.”*
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix

Comment: In that particular case, yes. In general, no. _Subsume_ and _presume_ are not opposites, for example, and nor are _suffer_ and _prefer_.